# SQL Server XML Path adding weekname on root element

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to experiment with SQL Server 2008's `FOR XML PATH` feature. But I'm not getting the output I expected.

I have a table like this:

```
     EventId EventDesc WeekName
     --------------------------------
     101      A          sunday
     102      B          Monday
     103      C          wednesaday
```

How to get output as XML like this:

```
<Events>
  <sunday>
     <E>
        <NE>
           <EventId>101</EventID>
           <Name>A</Name>
        </NE>
     </E>
   </sunday>
   <Monday>
      <E>
         <NE>
            <EventId>102</EventID>
            <Name>B</Name>
         </NE>
      </E>
   </Monday>
   <Tuesday>
      <E>
         <NE>
            <EventId>103</EventID>
            <Name>C</Name>
         </NE>
      </E>
   </Tuesday>
</Events>
```

The query I used:

```
select  
    (select 
        [EventID] as ID, 
        [EventDesc] as D
     from 
        TempEvent 
     where 
        WeekName = 'sunday' 
     FOR XML PATH('NE'), Root('E'), type)    
FOR XML PATH ('sunday')
```

My problem is, how to get weekname for each row in the XML output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the best solution (definitely not elegant ) as it uses string concatenation to build the `XML` but it gets the job done.

```
;WITH CTE as 
(
    SELECT 101 as EventId,      'A' as EventDesc,          'sunday' as WeekName
    UNION ALL SELECT      102 as EventId,      'B' as EventDesc,          'Monday'
    UNION ALL SELECT      103 as EventId,      'C' as EventDesc,          'wednesaday'
)
SELECT '<Events>' +(
SELECT DISTINCT '<' + WeekName +'>' + (SELECT EventId,EventDesc FROM CTE  C2 WHERE C2.WeekName = C1.WeekName FOR XML PATH('NE'),ROOT('E')) + '</' + WeekName +'>'
FROM CTE C1
FOR XML PATH('Events'),TYPE).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)') + '</Events>'
```